# Need help redirecting to index.html after password entered

Tags: javascript, html, alertify

```
<script>
function password(){
    alertify.prompt("INGRESE LA CLASE", function (e, str) {
        if (str=='123'){ 
            // here! how to get into the another page, like "index.html"
        } else {
            alertify.log('ERROR! INGRESE LA CLAVE');
        } 
    }); 
}
</script>

<a href="index.html" onClick="password(); return false;">AQUI</a>
```

It works Alertify, but after OK, need some code to open the page index.

Comment: Note that you aren't adding any security whatsoever.

Comment: Google for "javascript redirect"

Comment: Since you're using js for this ... you can set the window location direction with window.location='host/index.html' but I'm with SLaks ... nothing here is secure

Comment: You do realize that a title doesn't have to contain all your question's text right?

Comment: I also find it highly doubtful that you read "all answers", given that there are 7.5 million questions and probably significantly more answers...

Comment: Thanks for all attention, I think if put JS as a file in another folder, is more secure?

Comment: This is my firt time to consult in the place professional like here, i will correct my error in next time. Thats right, I had read so many answers about Alertify but not all.

Comment: The point is (regarding security), in order to run JS, the browser has to read the code.  If the browser can read it, so can the user.  Passwords MUST be handled on the server.

Comment: so, I dont know that is too late or any master can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is that the function redirects the current page to the page in the href attribute of the clicked link, then

```
<script>
function password(event){
    alertify.prompt("INGRESE LA CLASE", function (e, str) {
        if (str=='123'){ 
            // here! how to get into the another page, like "index.html"
            window.location.href = event.target.href;
        } else {
            alertify.log('ERROR! INGRESE LA CLAVE');
        } 
    }); 
}
</script>
<a href="index.html" onClick="password(event); return false;">AQUI</a>
```

This will redirect to any page you have on href, either index.html or anything else. I wouldn't recommend this approach, though...

Comment: It worked, I love it. May I ask you why don't recommend this code? it so wrong wrote?

Comment: The solution is right for the question you asked. But the approach of your code is very wrong. As others have pointed out, security and password checking has to happen on the server. Because any time you check (compare) a password in Javascript, any user can read it or circumvent it.

Comment: I Realize that answer didnt work in chrome, need help again!! About security I put the file of Js in the folder, the reader can open my file in server?

Comment: Recently I realize the reader can open my folder in server, any master can help? the same function but correct code, work in IE and Chrome... that is so much my ask, isnt it?

Comment: I have edited the answer to correct it. The problem was that I didn't reference the href property of window.location, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Using window.location you can do that.
window.location = "index.html";

Comment: I want to apply this code to all my pages. So I need the action back to my HTML and the JS save in a file.js, thanks you!

Comment: I need the code to link to the page xxx of <a href= xxx.html.,..> and then I can apply this JS to all the page that need the password to link.